# I want to filter the Lines read form text file with set of the key words

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have written below code, it is working for the one word but when I give the seq variable term I am not getting the output, can anyone tell me how to solve this.

```
val term = List("Achieving","Making")

val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]","Filter_lines")

val Lines = sc.textFile("../book.txt")

val filter_Lines = Lines.filter(l => l.contains("Making")).collect()

filter_Lines.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Lines.filter(l => term.exists(t => l.contains(t))).foreach(println)
```

exists function on the collection accepts a function that returns true if the "l" contains any of the "t" terms.

Comment: Glad I could help